# How to draw a map with a large database in android?

Tags: android, database, animation, canvas, dictionary

I'm trying to draw a map ( but not using google map) and make an animation with it (like zoom, scroll rotate, transition....) . It works very smooth with the small database, but when i test with the large database (about 15000 points and lines), it take more than minutes to start a small activity (like zoom)... 
In the code, i draw all the map into the canvas type, then use matrixs and thread to make animation.
I want to ask if there is a other way to make it faster.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While user starts zooming, convert your map to bitmap and zoom one image instead of thousands of objects. Also it's better to don't draw invisible (for user) objects